# Unable to instantiate fragment com.nisarg.locsav.PhotoGallery: could not find Fragment constructor

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I am facing a issue where i have created a fragment, nothing is wrong but still fragment does not open up. Here is my fragment:

```
class PhotoGallery extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    PhotoGalleryAdapter photoGalleryAdapter;
    PlaceViewmodel placeViewmodel;
    Observer<List<photo_n>> galleryobserver;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater infla, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savd)
    {
        View verti=infla.inflate(R.layout.photoviewergallery,parent,false);
        placeViewmodel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(PlaceViewmodel.class);
        recyclerView=verti.findViewById(R.id.gridrecycler);
        galleryobserver=new Observer<List<photo_n>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<photo_n> photo_ns) {
                ArrayList<photo_n> photo_ns1=new ArrayList<photo_n>();
                for(photo_n photo:photo_ns)
                {
                    photo_ns1.add(photo);
                }
                if(photoGalleryAdapter==null)
                {
                    photoGalleryAdapter=new PhotoGalleryAdapter(getActivity(),photo_ns1);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(photoGalleryAdapter);
                }
                else
                {
                    photoGalleryAdapter.setPhotoList(photo_ns1);
                }
            }
        };
        placeViewmodel.chosenImages.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),galleryobserver);
        if(photoGalleryAdapter==null)
        {
            photoGalleryAdapter=new PhotoGalleryAdapter(getActivity(),new ArrayList<photo_n>());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(photoGalleryAdapter);
        }
        return verti;
    }
}
```

I have not even overriden the constructor, so it should not give the following problem. But it still gives so, i have searched all the questions on stack overflow but still didn't get the answer.What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it apparently you should write this correctly:

```
class PhotoGallery extends Fragment {
```

as

```
public class PhotoGallery extends Fragment {
```

Other wise it will keep on giving error. Surprisingly this doesn't happen automatically in my version of android studio, anyone having the same problem?